# A tabbed PDF reader that saves and restores the last session?

Tags: 16.04, pdf, foxitreader

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and I'm searching for a PDF reader with tabs, and one that will save my sessions upon closing and re-opening. Foxit Reader on Windows does this--if you close the program and reopen it, the PDFs you had open will be shown, as long as you have the "restore last session" box ticked.

However, Foxit on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't restore the last session even if you have that box ticked. I wonder if this option behaves properly on older versions. Is there a way to force Foxit to open the last session?

Or is there an alternative PDF reader I can use that has this ability as well as tabs?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/foxit-reader/?platform=linux) there is a list of alternatives for Linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Qpdfview** has a setting for saving open tabs:

[image: qpdfview screenshot]

You can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt install qpdfview
```

Comment: Thank you, this program works perfectly! And it's a lot more light-weight than Foxit.