# qpdfview doesn't remember the pdfs opened in last boot, how do I make it possible?

Tags: boot, software-recommendation, pdf

[Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805307/a-tabbed-pdf-reader-that-saves-and-restores-the-last-session)

I read the above answer and did the exact same thing. My needs are exactly the same as that OP. But when I rebooted my laptop, it showed none of the pdfs that I opened in last boot.

How do I make it possible? Is there a way?

btw, I'm on ubuntu.

I'm absolute linux beginner, so I'd love some guidance on how to install anything.

**Why didn't I use chrome viewer?**

Because chrome scrolling absolutely sucks in linux (even after doing everything like getting extension, getting imwheel etc). I tried chromium linux browser, it sucked as well for my purpose.

**Why didn't I use firefox?**

Its pdf reader was really great. But when I'd reboot and open firefox,this happened:

> File not found
>
> Firefox can’t find the file at
> /media/username/2A84B1604F54EF23/myfolder/myfile/mytopic/mysubtopic/mybookname.pdf.
>
> Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors. Check
> to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

Ofc, Neither the name is error, nor the file has been moved. That’s why I’m asking the question.

I tried the fixes for everything (chrome+firefox) in askubuntu.com. It didn't work.

**Edit:**

I saw this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805307/a-tabbed-pdf-reader-that-saves-and-restores-the-last-session). I'd try this out. But I'd be happy with updated answers(even if they're on that post itself).

I tried to install mupdf using terminal, it didn't work (even though it kind of told it succeed).

[I followed this article](https://explorelinux.com/how-to-install-mupdf-in-ubuntu-linux/)

Looks like this is command based, I don't want that hassle. I just want a normal pdf viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Ubuntu but I've been using for a while and Okular usually solves this for me. You can download it in the software store, it's pretty simple.